# Is there an idiomatic way to define whether a property can be either type A or type B?

Tags: rust

I'm working on an application that will be messaging over TCP.

```rust
pub struct Message<T> where T: IsMessageType{
    message_type: T,
    length: u16,
    payload: [u8],
}
```

I want message types to be either IncomingMessageType or OutgoingMessageType. Both of these types are enums that represent data types that can be passed back and forth through the TCP stream, however because the operations that can be done on them are different I don't want to represent them as a single type.
Is there an idiomatic way to represent this constraint?

My current implementation is below.

```rust
//Define empty trait
pub trait IsMessageType{

}

pub enum IncomingMessageType {
    GetGPPVersion,
    GetDSPVersion,
    GetFPGAVersion,
    SetGPPVersion(Version),
    SetDSPVersion(Version),
    SetFPGAVersion(Version),
    StopGPP,
    StartGPP,
    DownloadBinaries,
}

//Implement the trait for the incoming message type
impl IsMessageType for IncomingMessageType{

}

pub enum OutgoingMessageType{
    GetGPPVersion,
    GetDSPVersion,
    GetFPGAVersion,
    ACK,
    NACK,
}

//And the outgoing message type
impl IsMessageType for OutgoingMessageType{

}
```

This satisfies the type bound, but I'm wondering if there's a better way to do this

Comment: Why not just layer on another enum on top of the existing two types?

Comment: That's too obvious :) Thanks!

Comment: Hmm after using another enum I remember why I wanted to use generics. I want some functions to only return incoming messages or handle outgoing messages, but other functions should accept or return either. If I wrap these enums in another enum then I lose the ability to specify that a function only returns a message type of IncomingMessage, for example

Comment: I would implement `TryFrom<Message> for IncomingMessage` and `From<IncomingMessage> for Message` and like for `OutcomingMessage`